# Не отправляются почтовое сообщения c# SmtpClient?

Tags: c#, wpf, mailkit

```
using MimeKit;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MailKit.Net.Smtp;

namespace pochta
{
    public class EmailSender
    {
        public void SendEmail(string to, string subject, string body)
        {
            var message = new MimeMessage();
            message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("lasdwer", "lasdwer@yandex.ru"));
            message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("klimjykov@yandex.ru", to)); // Адрес получателя
            message.Subject = subject;
            message.Body = new TextPart("мда")
            {
                Text = body
            };

            using (var client = new SmtpClient())
            {
                client.Connect("smtp.yandex.ru", 465, true);
                client.Authenticate("lasdw**", "ixybh******gsll");
                client.Send(message);
                client.Disconnect(true);
            }
        }
    }
}

     private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     EmailSender emailSender = new EmailSender();
     emailSender.SendEmail("klimjykov@yandex.ru", "Мда", "Мда");
 }
```

В яндексе все галки проставил в настройках, пароль приложения сделал, в client.Authenticate логин пароля и пароль приложения ввожу. Приложение в ошибку не падает если ввести неверный пароль или порт ошибка.

Comment: тут что то есть по теме https://stackoverflow.com/a/34850434/312041

Answer (score 0):

код оказался рабочим просто в яндекс почте не сразу прогружается папка спам:)